# How to customize the appearance of the password fields of a Django custom registration form?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to change the appearance of the input fields in the registration form, but why are the changes only applied to the username and email fields, but not to password1 and password2?

*forms.py*

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
    widgets = {
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
            'type': 'email',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'exampleInputEmail',
        }),
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'exampleInputUsername',
        }),
        'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'type': 'password',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'exampleInputPassword1',
        }),
        'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'type': 'password',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'exampleInputPassword2',
        }),
    }
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="mb-3 text-start">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
    {{ form.email }}
</div>
<div class="mb-3 text-start">
    <label for="exampleInputUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
    {{ form.username }}
</div>
<div class="mb-3 text-start">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
    {{ form.password1 }}
</div>
<div class="mb-4 text-start">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword2" class="form-label">Confirm password</label>
    {{ form.password2 }}
</div>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGzxg.png]

Comment: Can you please post the rendered html

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGzxg.png

Comment: no I mean the rendered html code

Comment: I added this to the question

Comment: no I mean the html delivered to your browser (right-click the page and go to "source")